# Import csv to python list

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file with about 200.000 records.

Each record has a title number, and some string information:

```
Title_1, Line_1_1, Line_1_2
Title_2, Line_2_1, Line_2_2
Title_3, Line_3_1, Line_3_2
```

I need to read this file into a list that looks like this:

```
data = [[Title_1, Line_1_1, Line_1_2], [Title_2, Line_2_1, Line_2_2], [Title_1, Line_3_1, Line_3_2]]
```

How can import this CSV to the list I need using Python?

Comment: Use the `csv` module.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most direct way, but my initial thought is to use the Pandas library!

```
import pandas as pd

your_file_path = "route1/route2/csv_file.csv"
df = pd.read_csv("your_file_path")
df.head(5)
```

With your CSV in a dataframe format, you can now pull the values you want out into a list.

```
output_ls = []
for index, row in df.itertuples():
    output_ls.append([row])
```

Comment: pandas is a pretty huge dependency to add when the standard library includes a `csv` module.

Answer (score -1):

```py
import csv

with open("yourcsv.csv", newline="") as y:
   data = csv.reader(y)
   data_list = list(data)
    
print(data_list)
```